# How can I make each individual frog stop using onTouch?

Tags: android, object, arraylist, android-studio, graphic

I am making a game where there there are frogs hopping around the screen. Once a frog is touched, I change the game image to what I have set as "deadFrog" and its movement stops. I have them all created under and array-list, and I am unsure as to how to only make changes to the individual frog. Right now, if one frog is tapped, all of the frogs stop moving and change to deadFrog. Hopefully you can help me fix the tactical nuke of a tap ;) *If you need any more information, just comment and I'll be sure to provide it!

**Edit** Is there not a way to access a single element in the blocks arraylist? I've tried doing blocks(1) for example but that's invalid.

Here is where the frogs are declared:

```
public void init() {
    blocks = new ArrayList<Block>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Block b = new Block(i * 200, MainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - 95,
                BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_HEIGHT);
        blocks.add(b);
        tapped = false;
    }
}
```

They are rendered with this:

```
private void renderFrogs(Painter g) {
    if (!tapped) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            Block b = blocks.get(i);
            if (b.isVisible()) {
                Assets.runAnim.render(g, (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY());
            }
        }
    }
    if (tapped) {
            for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
                Block b = blocks.get(i);
                if (b.isVisible()) {
                    g.drawImage(Assets.deadfrog, (int) b.getX(), (int) b.getY());
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

And this is the onTouchListener:

```
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        recentTouchY = scaledY;
    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            Block b = blocks.get(i);
            if ((scaledY >= b.getY() - BLOCK_HEIGHT || scaledY <= b.getY()) &&   (scaledX >= b.getX() || scaledX <= b.getX() + BLOCK_WIDTH)) {
                tapped = true;
            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course all frogs turn dead, you are supposed to keep "tapped" variable for each frog, your tapped variable is for all frogs at once.

Declare a class

```
public class Frog extends View{
   public Drawable liveFrog;
   public Drawable deadFrog;
   public boolean isDead;
   public Point location;
   public int width;
   public int height;

  public Frog(Context context, int x, int y,int width,int height){
      super(context);
      this.isDead = false;
      this.location = new Point(x,y);
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
   }


public void onDraw(Canvas c){
   super.onDraw(c);
      if(!isDead){
        //draw live frog at x,y
      }else {
          //draw dead frog at x,y
      }
 }
}
```

then you array is supposed to contain frogs

```
public void init(Context context) {
    blocks = new ArrayList<Frog>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      Frog b = new Frog(context,i * 200, MainActivity.GAME_HEIGHT - 95,
            BLOCK_WIDTH, BLOCK_HEIGHT);
        blocks.add(b);

    }
}

private void renderFrogs() {
        for(Frog f : blocks){
               //cause redraw
                 f.invalidate();
         }
    }

here comes the fun part, when you tap the frog


   public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        recentTouchY = scaledY;
    } else if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size(); i++) {
            Frog frog = blocks.get(i);
            if ((scaledY >= frog.getY() - BLOCK_HEIGHT || scaledY <= frog.getY()) &&   (scaledX >= frog.getX() || scaledX <= frog.getX() + BLOCK_WIDTH)) {
                frog.isDead = true;
                 //cause one frog redraw
                frog.invalidate();

               //if the event was handled, stop here (unless you can have multiple frogs one on top of the other ? 
              return true;
            }
        }

    }
     //if the event was not handled, let it bubble up
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What should I include in the invalidate method in the frog class?

Comment: the invalidate method is a system method - do NOT override it;)
it calls the onDraw method , you must override that

Comment: in the render frogs method, you must also add all your frogs to the view before you invalidate them, they must be attached to something
use the "addView" method

Comment: Thanks Lena, I will see what I can do and I will post a solution once I have figured it out

Comment: I figured it out, should I post a copy of the solution here or edit my main question and post my new code at the bottom?

Comment: if you find my answer helpful, please mark it. and yes I would appreciate seeing your solution, just put an "EDIT" in your question, stating the answer

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, your "tapped" boolean is not a property of EACH frog. It is declared once, and when triggered, per your for loop, will make every frog dead (obviously, since that's what you're experiencing).

Once "tapped" is true, your for loop is going through every block and assigning a dead frog to it.

I think you need to create a Frog class, and store instances of those in your ArrayList. A variable of the new frog class will be "touched", and when that is triggered you will do something to that specific instance only.

Comment: Okay I"m following you BG_NE. How do I access that specific instance?

Comment: I got it! Should I post the new code in this comment box?